# Fractional/rational form of $0.999...$

Tags: fractions, rational-numbers

Is it possible to express $0.999...$, a repeating number, as a fraction? Or as a ratio of two numbers?

Basically all (my) attempts at the problem cancels all the terms and returns $1$. Is it even possible? Or has it been proven to be an exercise of futility?

Comment: If by $0.999\cdots$ you mean $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 9/10^n$ then that's $1$.

Comment: $0.999\ldots=1$ as said many times before.

Comment: Go here $\longrightarrow$ https://www.livescience.com/57849-greatest-mathematical-equations.html and go through all the slides with the $11$ most beautiful equations in mathematics. You will see one equation in particular, namely $$1 = 0.999999999999999999\ldots$$

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it can: $0.999999999999\ldots=\dfrac11$.

Answer (score 4):

Let $$x=0.99999\ldots ,$$ now $$10x=9.99999\ldots ,$$ then $$10x-x=9x=9\Rightarrow x=1.$$

Answer (score 2):

$$0.9999\dots= 3*0.3333\dots= 3 * \frac 1 3=1$$

Answer (score 1):

0.9 lacks 1 by 0.1

0.99 lacks 1 by 0.01

0.999 lacks 1 by 0.001

0.9999 lacks 1 by 0.0001

0.9999.... lacks 1 by 0.0000...

Hence it is equal to 1